# Syntax error while calculating nearest location

Tags: php, laravel

`enter code here`I guess its pretty straightforward, But surely i am missing something here.
What I am trying to achieve here is to calculate the nearest location using the current position. Without adding the calculation part the query works fine.

I get an error saying "syntax error, unexpected 'AS' (T_AS), expecting ',' or ')'"

Any help will be appreciated.

```
enter code here
$testjoin = doctors::where('location_id',$data['location_id'])
                        ->where('medication_id',$data['medication_id'])
                        ->where('specialization_id',$data['specialization_id'])
                        ->where('facility_id',$data['facility_id'])
                        ->where('distance','<=',20)->orderBy('distance','desc')->take('20')
                ->join('locations', 'doctors.location_id', '=', 'locations.id')
                ->join('medication_types', 'doctors.medication_id','=','medication_types.id')
                ->join('specializations', 'doctors.specialization_id','=','specializations.id')
                ->join('facility_types', 'doctors.facility_id','=','facility_types.id')
                ->select(
                    'doctors.id',
                    'doctors.location_id',
                    'doctors.first_name',
                    'doctors.contact',
                    'doctors.email',
                    'doctors.lat',
                    'doctors.lng',
                    'locations.location',
                    'medication_types.medication',
                    'specializations.specialization',
                    'facility_types.type',
                    DB::raw( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(15.538210) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * 
                cos( radians( lng ) - radians(73.822974) ) + sin( radians(15.538210) ) * 
                sin( radians( lat ) ) )  AS distance )
                )->get();
```

Comment: __Quotes__, do you have them?

Comment: Count your `(` and `)` You have one to many

Comment: Please check your query. Normally "->select()" in only to select the fields that you need. By i can see there others things like "from having oderby limit" maybe these need to be outside of select.

Comment: @u_mulder tried with Quotes as well. Error still persists

Comment: I just think you query is wrong.

Comment: Which part Sir? @ManuelEduardoRomero

Comment: I added an answer (here i cant use format code) :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you cant do calculations in select. Select () only select the fields. Please try change the calculation

```
 ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(15.538210) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * 
       cos( radians( lng ) - radians(73.822974) ) + sin( radians(15.538210) ) * 
       sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance
```

By

```
 DB:raw( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(15.538210) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * 
       cos( radians( lng ) - radians(73.822974) ) + sin( radians(15.538210) ) * 
       sin( radians( lat ) ) )  AS distance )
```

You can use DB:raw to prepare a new column in you selected fields.

And please check "from","having","limit", "orderby" all this could be used as method of the doctors models. For eg.

```
->where('distance','<=',20)->orderBy('distance','desc')->take('20')->get()
```

Please try this and let me know how it works :)

Comment: Manuel Eduardo Romero . Sir where exactly should i place DB:raw?

Comment: Could you paste your new query?

Comment: DB::raw has an string as paramenter DB::raw('(6....')  please check this.

Comment: Sir, Query runs without an error, but the column 'distance' is not created in the table. :(

Comment: No, because distance is a new value created as alias.